# Finding a $f(n)$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k)$ equals the natural logarithm of a sinusoid

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, discrete-calculus

Let $g(n) = A\sin(\omega n + \phi)$ be a generic sinusoid, where $n$ is a positive integer.

Suppose that we want to find $f(n)$ such that

$f(1) + f(2) + \cdots + f(n)  = \ln[g(n)]$, or equivalently  $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k) = \ln[A\sin(\omega n + \phi)]$

#### Question

- Is there a $f(n)$ that satisfies the relation above?
- If we can't find such $f(n)$, and decide to make it simpler by setting:

i) $\omega = 1, A = 1, \phi = \pi/2$

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k) = \ln[\cos(n)]$

or

ii) $\omega = 1, A = 1, \phi = 0$

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k) = \ln[\sin(n)]$

now, can a solution be found?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The solution to $\sum_{k=1}^n f(k) = g(n)$ is $f(1) = g(1)$ and for $n > 1$, $f(n) = g(n) - g(n-1)$.